# Placing power supply problem

Tags: power-supply

In my project I want to use two power supplies of the type HLG-600H-24 with a power of 600W each and a efficiency of 95%. In the installation manual it tells me that each power supply should be at least 10-15 cm away from the next heat-generating source. Unfortunately I do not have enough space for that, the maximum distance is 3 cm. Now I assumed that with a heat power of 30W each this distance should not be a problem if I add flowing air to the setup (in between the power supplies. Is it possible to place them nearer to each other in this case, or should I still rely on the installation manual?
Data Sheet: http://www.meanwell.com/search/HLG-600H/HLG-600H-spec.pdf
Installation manual: http://www.meanwell.com/webnet/search/doc/DE/LED.pdf

Comment: What does the data sheet say? What does the manufacturer say? How about links to the data sheet?

Comment: @Andyaka: Added links to data sheet and installation manual

Comment: Well the data sheet says that derating applies at temperature above 55 degC and if both together on load don't generate a local temperature that is more than 55 then you should consider this option.

Comment: The temperature could rise over 55 °C, but not with full load, thus it should be possible.